# HTTP Status 404 after deploying a web application with a custom realm to Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat6, jdbcrealm, context.xml

I develop a web application for Tomcat 6, and I'm face to face with a problem I don't know how to resolve. Let's consider the following small scenario. Imagine that it's required to authenticate users not just by user and password, the authentication is only granted if some extra conditions are true (e.g. user, password, and his IP address matches). As far I understood, Tomcat introduced the concept of realms. A simple `JDBCRealm` was enough for the application, because the user and password pair was checked only until the moment. Now it's required to check the IP address too. I have written a simple test class that extends the `JDBCRealm` class:

```
package security;

import org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class ApplicationRealm extends JDBCRealm {

    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public synchronized Principal authenticate(Connection connection, String userName, String credentials) {
        logger.info("custom realm test, the authentication will be failed just for testing");
        return null;
    }

}
```

And then I have tried to bind this realm class using the `context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Realm className="security.ApplicationRealm" connectionName="${user}" connectionPassword="${password}"
        connectionURL="${url}${database}" debug="99" driverName="${driver}" roleNameCol="role" userCredCol="pw"
        userNameCol="login" userRoleTable="users_roles" userTable="users"/>
</Context>
```

The deployment of the web application succeeds, but when I try to access the login page, Tomcat returns a 404 page (I suspect the root of the problem is the `className` attribute in the `Realm` node):

`HTTP Status 404 -`
`type Status report`
`message`
`description The requested resource () is not available.`
`Apache Tomcat/6.0.24`

How can I bind a custom `JDBCRealm` descendant in `context.xml`? Maybe I'm totally wrong trying to use the `JDBCRealm` for this, but I can't see the correct solution anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the logs for stack traces.

Comment: what's in the logs? (tomcat/logs)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen , I tried to check the logs before, but it seems that nothing is written to the log.

Comment: @Bozho unfortunatelly nothing. Tomcat is not reporting about this error to the log.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv: Have you placed the security.ApplicationRealm in your WEB-INF/lib or the tomcat_home/lib?

Comment: @JoseK: Actually I tried it, but that failed too. As far as I understood later, the realm should be contained in a separate JAR that's independent from the web application archive. Also, it should be registered in the context.xml and server.xml, and the Tomcat server should be restarted. After doing this stuff, the realm worked. Another problem was I didn't know how to retrieve the HTTP request to check the IP in the realm. However, someone suggested just to use filters, because they do not require to change server.xml. I'm not sure about the best solution for this at the moment.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv: Well depending on your actual use case, you could look at using the Valve http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter for restricting/allowing users by IP address or IP range.

Comment: @JoseK: Thanks, I'll take that into account too. Anyway, is it possible to check the login/password/ip-address triple from a database using Valve?

Comment: Not out of the box. I'm really not sure if this is a good idea - but you can see the source code of this Valve http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Sevlet-Container/apache-tomcat-6.0.14-src/org/apache/catalina/valves/JDBCAccessLogValve.java.htm which shows how to interact with the database. This is for writing Access Log into a table.

Comment: @JoseK: FormAuthenticator (a descendant of the Valve class) is more suitable to resolve the problem because it also allows to check the remote address from the request, and it's exactly what I need. Thank you for pointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect deployment of the realm was the cause of the problem. Moreover, a custom realm is not suitable here. The best way of checking the IP-address is writing a custom form authenticator that have access to the HTTP request. Changing the form authenticator in the `web.xml`, and deploying it allowed exactly what I needed. It also eliminates the requirement to check IP-address on every request, because secure resources are hidden behind the authorization "wall" - this means if the authorization is granted, it also means that the IP was valid. Thanks to JoseK for pointing a good solution. I was just confused a little with the concept of realms in Tomcat.